# Unable to cast String type to Object type?

Tags: java, android

> Casting Object type to String ?

e.g. : a method `getResponse()` returns Object type of class

Request.

```
String s1=(String)req.getResponse();
```

Comment: what error u getting?

Comment: It is not possible right converting Object of unknowkn type to String Question Heading seems to be reversed

Comment: What do you expect ? `Request` is not a `String`

Comment: maybe like `String s1=req.getResponse().toString();`?

Comment: in my app when i want to login i am getting server error and if i changed string to object it is working so... @aifasin

Comment: sorry for bad explanation

Answer (score 6):

> Casting Object type to String?

In short, don't. You can however call [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29),

```
String s1 = req.getResponse().toString(); // <-- which may or may not be a useful
                                          // operation. If response doesn't override
                                          // toString() this will just return a class 
                                          // name and a hashcode.
```